# Fundamental group of $ \mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ minus $k$ disks $\mathbb{D}^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be the space obtained from $ \mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ by deleting $k$ disjoint  subsets, each one homeomorphic to $D^n$.

What is the foundamental group of $X$?

Comment: I want to use the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem, but I don´t see the apropiate open sets, any hint about this will be very useful for my, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cylinder with $k$ holes is homeomorphic to an open ball with $k+1$ holes, hence the fundamental group is given by the free product of $k+1$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

As a side question: how can you remove a $D^\color{red}{n}$ from a $2$-dimensional object?

Comment: He, My question was edited  because at  I wrote $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ not  $\mathbb{S}^{1}$

Comment: I think your answer has been made obsolete by the change in the question :/ and it's strange that the OP accepted the answer anyway, because it only works for $n=2$ (the fundamental group of $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ is not $\mathbb{Z}$, for example!).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: it was accepted because in the old formulation the problem was about removing disks from a cylinder, hence the case $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$. All the other cases are covered in the other answer.

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that the answer is not rigorous enough : "holes" are an intuitive way to think about spaces with nontrivial fundamental groups, but it's just not rigorous mathematics. If it's meant as a geometric visualization, please mention that in your post.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: The terminology "cylinder with $k$ holes" has a standard and completely rigorous definition in topology: it is a space obtained from a cylinder $S^1 \times [0,1]$ by removing the interiors of $k$ pairwise disjoint submanifolds of the interior of $S^1 \times [0,1]$ each of which is homeomorphic to $D^2$. One learns in topology how to prove that this is well-defined up to homeoeomorphism.

Comment: @LeeMosher I know what it is, but it's not obvious that having $n$ holes $\Longrightarrow$ $\pi_1 = *_n \Bbb Z$. I think it should be mentioned that it's homotopy equivalent to wedge of $n$ circles, and whatnot, otherwise it seems like it's an intuitive "visual" proof of problem.

Comment: Well, somebody can help me to understand the general answer because still do not understand in general, thanks.